# android: spinner not updating my view when notifyDataSetChanged() is called

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am trying to update the spinner view by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`. But its not updating.

The below is my Activity:

```
public class DisplayArchive2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<String> yearslist;
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.archive2);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.year_spinner);
        yearslist = new ArrayList<String>();
        yearslist.add("2017");
        yearslist.add("2016");
        yearslist.add("2015");
        yearslist.add("2014");
        yearslist.add("2013");

        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,yearslist);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                yearslist.clear();
                yearslist.add("2010");
                yearslist.add("2009");
                yearslist.add("2008");
                yearslist.add("2007");
                yearslist.add("2006");
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

The list of years is not changing on selecting any year.

It looks like below

[image]

Comment: try to reset adapter to spinner when dataset should be changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this use **`dataAdapter2.setNotifyOnChange(true);`** its working fine i have tested it my device

> [**`void setNotifyOnChange (boolean notifyOnChange)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#setNotifyOnChange(boolean))
>
> Control whether methods that change the `list (add(T)`, `addAll(Collection)`, `addAll(Object[])`, `insert(T, int)`, `remove(T)`, `clear()`, `sort(Comparator))` automatically call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. If set to false, caller must manually call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to have the changes reflected in the attached view. The default is true, and calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` resets the flag to true.

**CODE**

```
    List<String> yearslist;
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2;

     spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.year_spinner);
        yearslist = new ArrayList<String>();
        yearslist.add("2017");
        yearslist.add("2016");
        yearslist.add("2015");
        yearslist.add("2014");
        yearslist.add("2013");

       

            dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,yearslist);
            dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (position == 0) {

            } else {
                yearslist.clear();
                yearslist.add("2010");
                yearslist.add("2009");
                yearslist.add("2008");
                yearslist.add("2007");
                yearslist.add("2006");
                dataAdapter2.setNotifyOnChange(true);
                dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: So, you've got two adapters? That looks like a hacky solution

Comment: Then there's a typo here `dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Also you are creating and setting **dataAdapter2** two times

Comment: @EduardoHerzer by just mistake in copy paste of code

Comment: what is the use of notifyDataSetChanged().I am sorry sometimes i cant get into the documentation. Or when to use notifyDataSetChanged() and when to use setNotifyOnChange(true); Because when I work with pageradapter i used notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.  read more from docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I think even dataAdapter2.setNotifyOnChange(true); will not be required. Because i think its already set to true by default

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi when you add `setNotifyOnChange(true);` than no need to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` because `setNotifyOnChange()` automatically call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Also i want the list to be changed after selecting an item eg: 2015. But when i click on the spinner it open the changed list.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi check updated ans by default after adapter initialization  `onItemSelected()` called

Comment: In general spinner runs the code in the onItemSelected() when its gets initialized for the first time. But in this case why its not running. Can you see the below answer discussion. the list should change to 2006 to 2010 in the beginning itself. Ofcourse i dont want it so.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi yes I'm also surprised about it

Comment: BUt you said you checked it on you side also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162031/discussion-between-santhosh-yedidi-and-nilu).

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding. You are notifying the adapter inside `onItemSelected()`. In case of Spinner adapter initialization onItemSelected() will get called once for first time . So the list you will get in Spinner is always the new one(i.e 2006-2010) never the first one(i.e 2013-2017).
So if you do notify adapter on some other action or maybe avoid the first call to `onItemSelected()` your code will work fine .

Comment: I found in another place having this problem. But here its not having problem. Thats also very confusing. Sometimes it runs the code in onItemSelected() for the time and sometimes not.

Comment: Well, i am still surprised that how you get (2013-2017) list in your spinner . I have tested your code and it always shows the new list which is perfect as per documentation .

Comment: I am using Android 2.2.2 and Android SDK version 23.0.1 and compile SDK version is API 23. which i got from file>project Structure